# Excel file generated through azure function seems corrupted

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureportal, azure-http-trigger

Iam able to generate an excel using python pandas using:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns =["test"])
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f'{basepath}/Summary.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer,engine='openpyxl',sheet_name= 'Sample')
    writer.save()
```

But when i try to trigger it using an azure function with HTTP trigger the downloaded excel says:
[image]

Below is the code I have been using:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns =["test"])
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f'{basepath}/Summary.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer,engine='openpyxl',sheet_name= 'Sample')
    writer.save()
    response = func.HttpResponse(body=None,headers={'Content-Disposition':'attachment; filename='f'{basepath}/Summary.xlsx'}, mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel')
    return response
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to use the following code:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns =["test"])
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f'{basepath}/Summary.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer,engine='openpyxl',sheet_name= 'Sample')
    writer.save()

    with open(f'{basepath}/Summary.xlsx', "rb") as file:
        return func.HttpResponse(body=file.read(),headers={'Content-Disposition':'attachment; filename='f'{basepath}/Summary.xlsx'}, mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel')
```